# Wordpress - Can user login and create posts (pages) from the front end?

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a Wordpress site to let user to login and post a post(or a page) from the front end(similar to Stackoverflow). The user can login and post something, asking for a donation. And if somebody else read about your article and would like to donate you. They can do this by entering an amount to donate you. I know these are two functionality, but can Wordpress at least allow someone to login and create posts from the front end, or and plugins can help? Cheers.

Comment: I recommend you ask this question in http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ or WordPress forums.

Comment: Thx for your advice. I will do it.

Comment: **`If another browser is interested in you, they can donate you.`** *- - Is this a leftover from some translation app?* - - As it is now, you'll be asked for further clarifications in [wordpress.se] about what you mean and what you have researched. Check each site [help], so you can improve your Q.

Comment: Sorry, I just corrected my post. Hope it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the Front End Editor plugin for this in the past